# How to use "Set-AzureStorageFileContent" to upload file to HDInsight?

Tags: powershell, azure

I **think** I have setup my powershell environment to connect to my Azure account. I want to upload a file to my HDInsight *blob* storage. I did:

```
Set-AzureStorageFileContent -ShareName "what is a share name?" -Source "c:\local.file" -Path "test/"
```

But I got

```
Set-AzureStorageFileContent : Can not find your azure storage credential.     
Please set current storage account using 
"Set-AzureSubscription" or set the "AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING" environment variable.
```

The help information for **Set-AzureSubscription** is so useless, I have no idea what it is talking about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here:

- `Set-AzureStorageFileContent` uploads a file into [`File Service Share`](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files/) and not `Blob Storage`. To upload a file into blob storage, you would need to use [`Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806379.aspx) Cmdlet.
- I believe the error you're getting is because no storage account is specified. `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` cmdlet has a parameter called `Context` and you would need to specify the context which can do by calling [`New-AzureStorageContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495246.aspx) Cmdlet.

Sample code:

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName "accountname" -StorageAccountKey "accountkey"

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File "full file path" -Container "container name" -BlobType "Block" -Context $storageContext -Verbose
```

Please note that the container must exist in your storage account which you can create using [`New-AzureStorageContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806381.aspx) Cmdlet.